# Excel document parser/importer?

Tags: c++, c

Can anyone recommend a decent Excel (Binary XLS) document importer written in C?

I am looking to write a Ruby wrapper around one.

I haven't been able to find any via Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the source code of [Gnumeric](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cant' recommend anything to import XLS files directly, but I recently used [libcsv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/"libcsv") in a project of mine to import spreadsheets saved as CSV files into a C application.

In Excel, choose "File", "Save As" and set the "Save as type" to "CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv)" to save your file as a CSV.